# Webpacker in Rails 5 takes a long time to compile not that many files. How can I see what it's doing?

Tags: webpack, ruby-on-rails-5, webpacker

```
[Webpacker] Compiling…
```

It takes several seconds (6.2 seconds) to compile any of my changes to javascript files.  It's really slowing my JS development down.

Is there any way to see what Webpacker in Rails is doing and which files it's spending most of its time on?  It also be good if it could show me how much time each npm library was using.

I can manually run the `rails webpacker:compile` command but there doesn't seem to be any verbose mode on that.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I should've RTFM:

> If you want to use live code reloading, or you have enough JavaScript that on-demand compilation is too slow, you'll need to run `./bin/webpack-dev-server` or ruby .`/bin/webpack-dev-server`. Windows users will need to run these commands in a terminal separate from `bundle exec rails s`. This process will watch for changes in the `app/javascript/packs/*.js` files and automatically reload the browser to match.

Running `./bin/webpack-dev-server` uses live code reloading and is super fast!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  I too wonder why webpacker takes so incredibly long sometimes.  It would be helpful to see what packages are at fault.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question but it solves the problem

Comment: Using `./bin/webpack-dev-server` is not that fast on my macos.

Comment: Does not answer quesiton

Comment: It seems like it just automates the process of compilation on file change but doesn't provide any insight into the speed of compilation. I'm having the same issue where tailwind css takes ~19 seconds to compile every single css change. Conversely, compilation on save made it more clunky albeit being hot reloaded cause it's getting recompiled every time I tap cmd+s

Comment: Maybe it didn't answer the question but improved the js loading to the rocket speed. Thank you so much!

Comment: The problem with webpack-dev-server is that it functions differently than webpacker.  It throws a lot more errors, and for my current project is impacting some functionality

Answer (score 14):

`rails webpacker:compile` essentially just runs `bin/webpack`. See [compiler.rb#L59](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/86851d378/lib/webpacker/compiler.rb#L59). Unfortunately you can't pass it any options via `rake` but you can run it yourself in verbose mode to see what's going on:

```
bin/webpack --verbose
```

That's a bit hard to read and doesn't give good profiling information. You'll probably want to use the `--profile` flag instead:

```
bin/webpack --profile
```

This shows you the time it took to compile each of your packs and how large different chunks of code are.

**Edit**: I notice you said `webpack-dev-server` solves your problem in another answer. It may for now but our application takes 7 extra minutes to deploy because our JS is so bloated. I'm working on trimming things down and knowing the profiling information for each pack is a necessity to lowering our deploy times.

Comment: `bin/webpack --verbose --profile` also works and combines the output of the two commands

Answer (score 2):

Use `bin/webpack-dev-server` (open in separate terminal before `rails s`) - it is faster, but also slow by default

To speed up `webpack-dev-server` -

1. use `javascript_packs_with_chunks_tag` instead of `javascript_pack_tag`

```
    <%= Rails.env.production? ?
          javascript_pack_tag('application') :
          javascript_packs_with_chunks_tag('application') %>
```

2. add `environment.splitChunks()` to `config/webpack/environment.js`

```
if (process.env.RAILS_ENV != 'production') environment.splitChunks()
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much!! This really helped out with compilation.